# Why would App Engine Web Application terminate unexpectedly?

Tags: java, macos, google-app-engine

I just got prompted for a Java update on my iMac machine.  After the java update, my App Engine based Web Application (in Eclipse) won't start anymore.

The following was in the console (as usual) when I tried to debug it as Web Application:

```
<terminated exit value:139> myapp [Web Application] /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java (Mar 13,2011 7:20:27 pm)

2011-03-13 19:20:28.193 java[1772:903] [Java CocoaComponent compatibility mode]: Enabled
2011-03-13 19:20:28.194 java[1772:903] [Java CocoaComponent compatibility mode]: Setting timeout for SWT to 0.100000
Mar 14, 2011 2:20:29 AM com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger info
INFO: Logging to JettyLogger(null) via com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger
Mar 14, 2011 2:20:29 AM com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AppEngineWebXmlReader readAppEngineWebXml
INFO: Successfully processed /Users/tom/Workspace/myapp/war/WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml
Mar 14, 2011 2:20:29 AM com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AbstractConfigXmlReader readConfigXml
INFO: Successfully processed /Users/tom/Workspace/myapp/war/WEB-INF/web.xml
Mar 13, 2011 7:20:30 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl start
INFO: The server is running at http://localhost:8081/
```

And then the app just stops. The termination value seem to be 139.  Why does this happen and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Deleting the Java cache folder (~/Library/Caches/Java) (as posted in tom's link to the groups discussion) - although temporarily successful - did't solve the problem.
After re-installing the previous Java version, the eclipse GAE environment worked without any problems.